# Different toctree title and document title, specified in document source only

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext, toctree

When inserting a document in a toctree, the link displayed is the main title of the document. So when I do:

```
.. toctree::
   materials/diffuse
   materials/glossy
   materials/specular
```

I get:

Materials

- Diffuse material
- Glossy material
- Specular material

The word "material" is clearly redundant in the toctree, but is important in the document titles for good understanding.

RST allows me to write this:

```
.. toctree::
   Diffuse<materials/diffuse>
   Glossy<materials/glossy>
   Specular<materials/specular>
```

But I do not like this, as renaming a document requires updating the index toctree, and link updating is why I went from MediaWiki to Sphinx. Also, this disables the use of :glob: and wildcards in the toctree

**Question:** Is there any way to specify a toctree title in the leaf document itself, for instance in "diffuse.rst", as a meta-property?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In concept, the css content property would be applicable here.  Assuming your title is rendered with `<h1>` element, you'd want something like this:

```
.. raw:: html

   <style>
      h1:after {
         content: " Material";
      }
   </style>
```

The `<style>...</style>` block is doing the work.  Your docs keep the one word titles (Diffuse, Glossy, Specular) and the css adds " Material" on render.  So your pages have the title you want, and your toctree doesn't have the redundant "Material" for each item. However, you'd want that block to appear **only** on the pages in your "Materials" section -- you can't just add it to the main css file, or it will affect all `<h1>` elements.  Unfortunately, Sphinx doesn't have a mechanism for properly creating a `<style>` block in a page's `<head>` section, as far as I know.  Therefore to use this css technique you have to accept the complete hack of dropping it in a `.. raw:: html` directive as shown, somewhere on your page.  It won't really matter where you put it in your doc -- any location you choose will produce non-valid html, but will render what you want: your toctree labels will not contain "material"; your page titles will.